# How to keep divs changes by ng-view recall during async operation?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

It's ng-view with divs:

```
<div class="extClass" id="ext">
   <div class="intClass" id="int">
   </div>
</div>
```

With some control element is started asynchronous process which changes divs (their CSS-classes and styles + text). If during process to recall this ng-view, all divs changes are dumped in the default.

How keep divs changes by ng-view recall during performance of asynchronous process?

AngJS service method which start async process:

```
function startAsyncProc() {
   // get divs
   var extDiv = document.getElementById('ext');
   var intDiv = document.getElementById('int');
   // set internal div
   intDiv.style.width = '0%';
   intDiv.textContent = '0%';
   // create and set reader
   reader = new FileReader();
   // .. process handler
   reader.onprogress = function(e) {
   var value = ...; // somehow calculated 
   if (...) {
         intDiv.style.width = value + '%';
         intDiv.textContent = value + '%';
    }
   }
   // .. process start handler
   reader.onloadstart = function(e) {
       extDiv.style.opacity = '1.0';
   };
   // .. process end handler
   reader.onload = function(e) {
       setTimeout("extDiv.className='extСlass';", 2000);
   };
   // start process
   reader.readAsText(...);
};
```

Comment: Please show us the code that make these changes

Comment: Thank for your attention. Updated post.

Comment: Angular creates new I thing, you can bind the new one thought

Comment: You really should try to avoid DOM manipulation when using angular.  From what I can tell from your code, `ng-style` would probably solve a lot of your problems.